# Debug a Nagios NRPE command

Tags: nagios, nrpe

My nagios fail with fail2ban service. Whith an other command it's Ok:

> nagios@server:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins$ /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c "check_load"
>
> OK - load average: 0.00, 0.06, 0.08|load1=0.000;15.000;30.000;0; load5=0.060;10.000;25.000;0; load15=0.080;5.000;20.000;0;

With fail2ban service it don't work. This fail2ban script test this (see http://pastebin.com/1utP9iM6):

```
$(ps aux |grep "fail2ban.sock" |grep -v grep| wc -l)
```

If i test it with nagios user it correctly return **1**. But when it's executed by NRPE it fail:

> nagios@server:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins$ /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c "check_fail2ban" /var/log/fail2ban.log /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf 10 20
>
> 0
>
> ++++ Process is not running ++++

How can i debug more to found what is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could let the script log something to a file, e.g.:

```
ps aux > /tmp/debugfile
```

An alternative would be using the generic check_procs:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1:1 -C fail2ban-server
```

Comment: The ps output nothing for fail2ban. Thank's for "check_procs". I finally use it instead of my fail2ban script.